# Show button as header in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

The requirement is to create an lwc page where buttons show as header but if i am trying to put button inside the outermost template in the html file the button comes inside the body.
How can i achieve this via lightning web component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to show a button outside of the `lightning-card`.

So I am posting a code below for your reference

```
<template>
 <lightning-button label="Neutral" title="Non-primary action" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
 <lightning-button label="Neutral" title="Non-primary action" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
     <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title="Hello" icon-name="standard:account">
            <lightning-button-icon  icon-name="utility:down" variant="border-filled" alternative-text="Show More" slot="actions"></lightning-button-icon>
            <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">Card Body Narrow (custom component)</p>
            <p slot="footer">Card Footer</p>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Here is the link - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/iZVWKhC-G/1/edit